# R: How to read multiple xlsx files? Error: `path` does not exist:

Tags: r, dplyr

Guys I need your help.

I want to read a bunch of xlsx files, but for some reason it is not working.
My code follows some suggestions given in other stack overflow posts.
I apologise but there is no reproducible code, I am totally lost here.

```
tbl <-
  list.files(path = 'Data/', pattern = "*.xlsx") %>% 
  map_df(~read_excel(.))

Output: Error: `path` does not exist: ‘CRO-ALL-COUNTRIES.xlsx’
```

Now, if I run only the line

```
list.files(path = 'Data/', pattern = "*.xlsx")

Result: 
>  list.files(path = 'Data/', pattern = "*.xlsx")
[1] "CRO-ALL-COUNTRIES.xlsx"  
[2] "Direct-material-packaging-ALL-COUNTRIES.xlsx"   
[3] "Direct-material-Raw-material-ALL-COUNTRIES.xlsx"
```

I obtain all the files that are in that folder and CRO-ALL-COUNTRIES.xlsx is there!!!
Why can't I read it?

Comment: Either include `'Data/'` in your path, or use `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files()`. As of right now, it is looking in your current working directory for the file names.

Comment: full.names = TRUE did the work!

Comment: @Mig if you are happy with the answer are you able to give it a check mark so that it has been marked answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give this question a formal answer. If you look up `?list.files` the `full.names` argument is defaulted to FALSE. As Andrew indicated it was looking in your current working directory for your file. When you typed `full.names = TRUE` the directory path was prepended to the file names to give a relative path.

```
tbl <-
  list.files(path = 'Data/', pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  map_df(~read_excel(.))
```